# Send mail not working with contact.htm

Tags: debian, sendmail

I have a Ubuntu 14 server and trying to get my web site contact.htm to send mail to my address jplazzo@hotmail.com here is the mail.log :

```
Nov 18 17:22:34 ubuntu sendmail[7439]: tAIMMX5s007439: Authentication-Warning: ubuntu.localhost: www-data set sender to jplazzo@hotmail.com using -f
Nov 18 17:22:34 ubuntu sendmail[7439]: tAIMMX5s007439: from=jplazzo@hotmail.com, size=495, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201511182222.tAIMMX5s007439@ubuntu.localhost>, relay=www-$
Nov 18 17:22:34 ubuntu sm-mta[7440]: tAIMMYL6007440: from=<jplazzo@hotmail.com>, size=821, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201511182222.tAIMMX5s007439@ubuntu.localhost>, proto=ESMT$
Nov 18 17:22:34 ubuntu sendmail[7439]: tAIMMX5s007439: to=jplazzo@hotmail.com, ctladdr=jplazzo@hotmail.com (33/33), delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30495, $
Nov 18 17:22:35 ubuntu sm-mta[7442]: STARTTLS=client, relay=mx1.hotmail.com., version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=FAIL, cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384, bits=256/256
Nov 18 17:22:35 ubuntu sm-mta[7442]: tAIMMYL6007440: to=<jplazzo@hotmail.com>, delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=esmtp, pri=120821, relay=mx1.hotmail.com. [134.170.2.19$
Nov 18 17:22:35 ubuntu sm-mta[7442]: tAIMMYL6007440: tAIMMZL6007442: DSN: Service unavailable
Nov 18 17:22:36 ubuntu sm-mta[7442]: STARTTLS=client, relay=mx3.hotmail.com., version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=FAIL, cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384, bits=256/256
Nov 18 17:22:36 ubuntu sm-mta[7442]: tAIMMZL6007442: to=<jplazzo@hotmail.com>, delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=esmtp, pri=30000, relay=mx3.hotmail.com. [65.55.37.120]$
Nov 18 17:22:36 ubuntu sm-mta[7442]: tAIMMZL6007442: to=MAILER-DAEMON, delay=00:00:01, mailer=local, pri=30000, dsn=5.1.1, stat=User unknown
Nov 18 17:22:36 ubuntu sm-mta[7442]: tAIMMZL6007442: to=postmaster, delay=00:00:01, mailer=local, pri=30000, dsn=5.1.1, stat=User unknown
Nov 18 17:22:36 ubuntu sm-mta[7442]: tAIMMZL6007442: tAIMMZL7007442: return to sender: User unknown
Nov 18 17:22:36 ubuntu sm-mta[7442]: tAIMMZL7007442: to=MAILER-DAEMON, delay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=0, dsn=5.1.1, stat=User unknown
Nov 18 17:22:36 ubuntu sm-mta[7442]: tAIMMZL6007442: Saved message in /var/lib/sendmail/dead.letter
```

Please let me know what is not working

Answer (score 0):

The log appears to indicate you are failing authentication with hotmail.

It also says you do not have the default rule MAILER-DAEMON for it to send you the errors, which is a requirement of the protocol ; please do create it and redirect it to your email. As this is not setup, the errors are being placed in /var/lib/sendmail/dead.letter and this file will grow over time.

Comment: What is the rule MAILER_DAEMON problem?